# Get duplicate rows from datatable based on single column

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, datatable

I am trying get rows from datatable based on single column value. I have `FiledName, FieldType, TableName` are column names.

below query is working fine but I am getting only `FieldName` only. Not all columns.

How to get all columns from below?

```
Dim duplicates = DataSourceTable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(Function(i) i.Field(Of String)("FieldName")).Where(Function(g) g.Count() > 1).Select(Function(g) g.Key)
    DataSourceTable = New DataTable
    Dim row As DataRow
    For Each dup In duplicates
        row = DataSourceTable.NewRow
        'row(0) = dup// I want get all values columns with index
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two steps here: one to get the duplicated FieldName values, and another to get the rest of the values you are interested in.  The easiest solution if to use a temp table:

INSERT INTO myTempTable(FieldName) SELECT FieldName FROM MySourceTable WHERE something = whatever GROUP BY FieldName HAVING count(*) > 1;

SELECT a.FieldName, a.FieldType, a.TableName FROM MySourceTable a JOIN myTempTable b ON (a.FieldName = b.FieldName) ORDER BY a.FieldName, a.TableName;

Answer (score 0):

If you need the entire row instead of only the keys of the groups, then just don't select only the keys.

Simply change

```
Dim duplicates = DataSourceTable.AsEnumerable()
                                .GroupBy(Function(i) i.Field(Of String)("FieldName"))
                                .Where(Function(g) g.Count() > 1)
                                .Select(Function(g) g.Key)
```

to

```
Dim duplicates = DataSourceTable.AsEnumerable()
                                .GroupBy(Function(i) i.Field(Of String)("FieldName"))
                                .Where(Function(g) g.Count() > 1)
```